# I am creating program in C to count words in file already created and save the words in new file in alphabetical order

Tags: c, file, sorting

I am a beginner in first grade at college taking programming. I have created code which counts words, but I am stuck on how to sort them into alphabetical order and write them to a new file. Following is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv)
{   
    char ch;
    FILE *subor;
    int pocet = 0;
    subor = fopen("subor.txt","r");

    while((ch = fgetc(subor)) != EOF){
        if(ch ==' ' || ch == '\n')
            pocet++;
    }

    printf("Pocet slov v subore je: %d", pocet);
    fclose(subor);

    if (argc < 2) return 1;

    char * nazovsuboru = argv[1];
    FILE * fp = fopen(nazovsuboru, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Can you help me add the function to save words in alphabetical order to a new file?

Comment: The easiest way is to read in word for word and put it into a binary tree like structure, using `strcmp()` with the node value. If the result is `-1` descend the left tree, `+1` for the right tree. Then do an in-order traversal and write each node value to the target file.

Comment: If you are allowed to use `qsort()`, then this function can make your task even easier.

Comment: I think the good method you should adopt (before asking on a forum like SO) is to do a search on the web. As you can imagine (even if yo are a beginner) you are not the first programmer who needs to sort words (or anything else). Good luck

Comment: @Ctx: "*The easiest way is to read in word for word and put it into a binary tree ..*" well ... are you sure? ;)

Comment: You can break this down to two subproblems. 1) Store the words in a list. 2) Sort the list. Another way of looking at it is to just implement a queue and then print all the words in the queue. All three problems have been solved millions of times. Just search.

Comment: @alk Hm, assuming that no highlevel functions may be used, at least _I_ would consider it easier as for example trying to build a sorted linked list item by item or something cludgy like that ;)

Comment: regarding: `char ch;` and `while((ch = fgetc(subor)) != EOF){`  The function: `fgetc()` returns an `int` not a `char`.  EOF is an `int`

Comment: regarding: `int main(int argc, char * argv)`   The second parameter is not correct.  It should be: `int main( int argc, char * argv[] )`  or `int main(int argc, char ** argv)`

Comment: OT:  regarding: `subor = fopen("subor.txt","r");`  when calling `fopen()`   always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful..  If not successful, call `perror( "your error message" ); followed by: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: OT:  in general, should never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the user actually entered the expected number of command line parameters

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#define BUFSIZE     1024
#define DEFAULTSIZE 1024


int cmp_strings(const void * a, const void * b)
{
    return strcmp(*(const char **)a, *(const char **)b);
}


int main()
{
    char buffer[BUFSIZE];
    char * token;
    const char * delimiters = " \n,!?"; // add punctuation as necessary
    size_t word_counter = 0, nbytes;
    char * * words = malloc(DEFAULTSIZE * sizeof(char*));

    FILE * inputfile = fopen("filename.txt", "r");
    if (!inputfile) {
        perror("fopen");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while ((nbytes = fread(buffer, 1, BUFSIZE, inputfile)) > 0) {
        buffer[nbytes] = '\0';

        token = strtok(buffer, delimiters);
        while (token) {
            words[word_counter] = malloc((strlen(token)+1) * sizeof(char));
            strcpy(words[word_counter], token);
            word_counter++;
            token = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
        }
    }

    // sorting function from stdlib
    qsort(words, word_counter, sizeof(const char*), cmp_strings);

    FILE * outputfile = fopen("out.txt", "w");

    for (size_t i = 0; i < word_counter; i++) {
        sprintf(buffer, "%s\n", words[i]);
        fwrite(buffer, 1, strlen(buffer), outputfile);
        free(words[i]);
    }
    free(words);

    fclose(inputfile);
    fclose(outputfile);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Some notes:

- I made some assumptions regarding the number of words in the file and their maximum size. The exercise of adapting this program to a situation where is not the case will be left *as an exercise for the reader*. For example, you could achieve this by using a linked list or just doing `realloc` whenever needed
- You should always check for function returns (i.e. `malloc` etc.), which I didn't do in order to keep the code as simple as possible